# How to Deploy asp.net mvc 4 application having multiple projects in area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, area

I followed [THIS TUTORIAL](http://geekswithblogs.net/cokobware/archive/2013/01/15/asp.net-mvc-4-pluggable-application-modules.aspx) to make pluggable MVC4 application using concept of Areas, where there is the Areas folder within main project and within that Areas folder there are multiple projects which acts like pluggable modules.

Now when I run app from visual studio everything works great, but when I try to deploy the main project the Areas folder is ignored ultimately ignoring all the projects and views within that Areas folder.

How to correctly deploy such application.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below suggestion

**Solution 1:**
We need to host separate sub module in ISS(that means Virtual/app directory in side the main application)

**Solution 2 :**
Just refer all project in ProductDemo main project(i think already you are done this)
Copy and paste inculding views in manin product demo folder

**Solution 3 :** Use Precompiled Razor View Using RazorGenerator MVC and PreCompiledViewEngine in MVC

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/97fc7a/article-precompiled-razor-view-using-razorgenerator-mvc-and/

Any difficulties in this, let us know also need more info... Thank you...